# C++ create a variable number of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, root

I have read columns from a .txt file (the file has at the beginning the number of columns (nCol)) and put the values into an array (float values[nCol][nLin]).

Now, I want to copy the values (ex.: values[0][nLin], values[1][nLin]...) into different float arrays depending on the number of columns.

How can I crate float arrays for each column if the number of columns my change depending on the file I am reading?

```
//------ Declares Array for values ------//
const int nCol = countCols;
float values[nCol][nLin];

// Fill Array with '-1'
for(int c=0; c<nCol; c++){
    for(int l=0; l<nLin; l++) {
        values[c][l] = -1;
    }
}


//------ Skips the reading of line of values file ------//
getline(inFile, dummyLine);

// reads file to end of *file*, not line 
while(!inFile.eof()) {
    for(int y=0; y<nLin; y++){
        for (int i=0; i<nCol; i++) {
            inFile >> values[i][y];
        }
    i=0;    
    }
}

const int nValues = countLines;

float Col1[nValues]=-1,
      Col2[nValues]=-1,
      Col3[nValues]=-1,
      Col4[nValues]=-1,
      Col5[nValues]=-1;

//------ Put values in specific Arrays ------//

for(int v=0; v<nValues; v++) {
        Col1[v] = values[0][v];
        Col2[v] = values[1][v];
        Col3[v] = values[2][v];
        Col4[v] = values[3][v];
        Col5[v] = values[4][v];
}
cout << endl;
```

I want that `float Col1[]` to be from 1 to nCol, the last one to be `float ColnCol[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way IMO would be to use `std::vector< std::vector<float> >`

You do not need to make different 1D columns as you can manipulate this vector of vector as you want.

Comment: But is it possible with arrays? I have made the rest of the program and calculations with arrays

Comment: I don't think your program will need to change much since vectors work almost same as arrays (ofcourse with a lot more functionality). And to answer your question, if the number of lines is dynamic, then fixed length arrays cannot be used.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you give an example of how could I do it with vectors?

Comment: Instead of Col1[k], use values[0][k] everywhere.

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should use `std::vector`. It is a better choice for dynamic size allocation of a data type.